# strcmp implementation not working with special characters

Tags: c, strstr

I'm trying to implement my own `strcmp` function, my `strcmp` bahaves differently when I use special characters.

```
#include <string.h>    

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    const char  *str1;
    const char  *str2;

    str1 = s1;
    str2 = s2;
    while ((*str1 == *str2) && *str1)
    {
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return (*str1 - *str2);
}

int main()
{
   char *src = "a§bcDef";
   char *des = "acbcDef";
   printf("%d %d\n", my_strcmp(des, src), strcmp(des, src));
   return(0);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> 161 -95

Comment: You need to return `*str2 - *str1` methinks.

Comment: @FUZxxl when I do that, I get `-161 and -95`, I'm not sure if, it is right because the sign are the same.

Comment: If the signs match, your function works correctly.

Comment: As FUZxxl said, if signs match your function works correctly.  Return values of `strcmp()` are specified as being negative, zero, or positive.   Specific negative or positive values are neither required not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the standard says about `strcmp`, with a relevant section highlighted in bold:

> The sign of a non-zero return value shall be determined by the sign
>   of the difference between the values of the first pair of bytes **(both
>   interpreted as type unsigned char)** that differ in the strings being
>   compared.

Your code is taking the difference of the bytes as `char`, which if signed differs from the spec.

Instead:

```
return (unsigned char)(*str1) - (unsigned char)(*str2);
```

Here's some test cases for the original code (`my_strcmp`), the currently accepted answer of dasblinkenlight (`my_strcmp1`), and this answer (`my_strcmp2`). Only `my_strcmp2` passes the tests.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const signed char *str1 = (const signed char*)(s1);
    const signed char *str2 = (const signed char*)(s2);

    while ((*str1 == *str2) && *str1)
    {
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return (*str1 - *str2);
}

int my_strcmp1(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const signed char *str1 = (const signed char*)(s1);
    const signed char *str2 = (const signed char*)(s2);

    while ((*str1 == *str2) && *str1)
    {
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return (signed char)(*str1 - *str2);
}

int my_strcmp2(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const signed char *str1 = (const signed char*)(s1);
    const signed char *str2 = (const signed char*)(s2);

    while ((*str1 == *str2) && *str1)
    {
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return (unsigned char)(*str1) - (unsigned char)(*str2);
}


int sgn(int a) {
    return a > 0 ? 1 : a < 0 ? -1 : 0;
}

#define TEST(sc, a, b) do { \
    if (sgn(sc(a, b)) != sgn(strcmp(a, b))) { \
        printf("%s(%s, %s) = %d, want %d\n", #sc, a, b, sc(a, b), strcmp((const char*)a, (const char*)b)); \
        fail = 1; \
    } } while(0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct {
        const char *a;
        const char *b;
    }cases[] = {
        {"abc", "abc"},
        {"\x01", "\xff"},
        {"\xff", "\x01"},
        {"abc", "abd"},
        {"", ""},
    };
    int fail = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cases) / sizeof(cases[0]); i++) {
        TEST(my_strcmp, cases[i].a, cases[i].b);
        TEST(my_strcmp1, cases[i].a, cases[i].b);
        TEST(my_strcmp2, cases[i].a, cases[i].b);
    }
    return fail;
}
```

(note: I put in some explicit `signed` in the implementations so that the code can be tested on compilers with unsigned char). Also, sorry about the macro -- this was a quick hack to test!

Comment: Nice, indeed ... :-)

Comment: And the only one disliking your macro seems to be the SO C source parser ... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`char` is signed in many implementations, and your `strcmp` implementation considers `char` values < 0 to be smaller than those greater than 0. Perhaps you want to compare the unsigned values instead.

```
const unsigned char *str1 = (unsigned char*) s1;
const unsigned char *str2 = (unsigned char*) s2;
```